# angularJS $http.get() request on a complicated JSON output

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have a PHP that gives out an output in the form JSON code like this :

```
{
    "data": {
        "groups": {
              "admin": [
                { "loginname" : user1 },
                { "loginname" : user2 }
              ],
              "group1" : [
                { "loginname" : user1 },
                { "loginname" : user2 }
              ]
            }
        },
    "status":"success"
}
```

Basically each loginname corresponds to a group name which is a variable (admin and group 1 in this case). How will I access the list of all groups from this output? The key of my php array is itself a variable making it difficult. Here is the link to the PHP : https://gist.github.com/raghunayyar/cf8d29d9e4ccc0423125. Ask me if any more info is required. :)

Comment: Can you let us know what is the final value that you are expecting? I am confused with the structure of your model - so maybe you could just let us know what value you are expecting...

Comment: I want to get the list of groups(admin, group1), and list of users belonging to that particular group(user1,user 2 for both the groups.).

Comment: Where do you want to get it? As in, do you want this information in your controller or in your view?

Comment: ohh, okay view, basically a list like <li ng-repeat = "group in groups"> I have already defined controllers and the remaining stuff. :)

Comment: you want to create `ul` list with all groups in it?

Comment: yeah, as I said before. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you store the JSON response `data` value in a variable called `data`, it sounds like you just need something like this in your view:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(group, users) in data.groups">
    <p>Group: {{group}}</p>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="user in users">{{user}}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This would print a list of groups with a sub-list of users.  Here is a [link](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat) to the Angular documentation on the `ng-repeat` directive.